# How can pick and capture image in android 4.4?

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I Have use capture and pick image in using  camera  intent when every time call on on create activity ?
How it can be solve? And also give example.

Comment: hi applay   android:largeHeap="true" in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" but not any changes

Comment: Try this may be helpfull https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide

Answer (score 0):

you have call capture method from **onCreate** only .

This link help you to create  your camera application

[Camera Using Intent & Custom Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#q=SurfaceTextureManager)

I hope this is help you.

Comment: Let Me check Thanx @DreamCoder

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through button event instead of calling at `onCreate()`. Please write a little brief about your application that what is your requirement and all that, so it would be a little easy for us to understand.

Also check this http://androidexample.com/Camera_Photo_Capture_And_Show_Captured_Photo_On_Activity_/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=77&aaid=101

Comment: Problem is only Kitkat version for some phone ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE then intent finish then call on create activity for in kitkat version